# SASS Styles are not being generated in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

For some reason, my link tag of saas styles is not being generated in the output file of the index.html. Although the script tag is generating.

My index.js

```
import '../sass/main.scss'
```

My Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
            test: /\.scss$/i,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                }, 
                'resolve-url-loader', 
                'sass-loader'
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            use: ['html-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options:{
                  name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                  outputPath: "img/",
                  publicPath: 'img/'
                }
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
          template: "./src/index.html"
        }),
        //new CleanWebpackPlugin()
      ],
};
```

package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  }
```

File structure:

[image]

There are no errors with this file structure.

I tried `import './sass/main.scss'` but getting an error of module not found.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

After changes, I am getting an error on img url:

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../../data/img/back1.jpeg' in 'D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\src\sass'
    at finishWithoutResolve (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:293:18)
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:362:15
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:410:5
    at processResult (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:583:19)
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:676:5
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:397:11
    at D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
    at context.callback (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (D:\github work\portfolio-webpack-html-css\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:155:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
 @ ./src/js/index.js 6:0-26

1 ERROR in child compilations
webpack 5.11.1 compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning in 1225 ms
```

The image is in the img folder and the file _header.scss is the one I am setting my image URL.

[image]

And this is how I am setting the img path:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, rgba(85,89,93,1) 100%),
                 url('../../data/img/back1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
```

Comment: What is your problem? But looks like your generated styles would be included in your generated js code since you're using `style-loader`

Comment: @tmhao2005 My styles are not loading in the browser, When I checked my index.html, I didn't see my link tag for CSS. But there was a script tag. No idea what's wrong, everything seems fine to me with no errors. Is there anything else you would like me to share?

Comment: I recommend you to use a package which helps you to extract css into file & append  to your html plugin as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of keeping css as separate file, you need to use this package [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).

You can ref to the link to know how to install and configure. Here is the basic thing you would need to add to your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
// Keep in mind to install
// `npm i -D mini-css-extract-plugin`

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

{
  test: /\.scss$/i,
  use: [
      // 'style-loader', // stop using `style-loader`
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
              url: false
          } 
      }, 
      'resolve-url-loader', 
      'sass-loader'
  ],
},

// Add to your plugin as well
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
],
```

#### Update

Looks like the url path would relate with the index file where to import things `main.scss` instead so you have to change the path relative to the entry path. (The main file is transformed to css file then it would get passed to css loader then css-loader continues to process resolving url)

```js
background: url('../data/img/back1.jpeg') no-repeat center; // change to `../`
```

Keep in mind, to still keep `url` option being enabled for `css-loader` & dont' have to use `resolve-url-loader`

Comment: I tried this now I am getting a proper error. Edited my question with the error

Comment: Looks like your scss file contains url which isn't having the right path. Not sure why you stop css-loader from helping your url in your css file `{ url: false }`? If you can also post your reproducible repo, then I can help to look at

Comment: I removed it although I am still getting an error. I was trying different things to make this work, that's why by accident I left it there and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is my Github repo: https://github.com/ZaidKhan144/portfolio-webpack-html-css

Comment: Okay I’ll look at it tomorrow. It’s quite late here

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: Hi, did you got time to look into my issue?

Comment: I did update the answer for you already :) Look at the update area

Comment: I updated the URL path and also removed `resolve-url-loader`, the errors are gone, main.css is generated, there is a link tag in index.html as well but the styles are not applying in the browser. I can't see my image or any styles applied. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: It works fine in my end. Not sure how did you serve your app?

Comment: I've recorded what I served the built files https://www.loom.com/share/feec6611ace4435a9be79817596c1503

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226937/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-zaid-khan).

Comment: That's exactly how I want, did you changed anything else from the above changes I mentioned?